Register APO (Audio Processing Object) as SFX, MFX or EFX for all devices
My goal is to create Windows Equalizer similar to EqualizerAPO - https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/
In EqualizerAPO Configurator there is a way to select placement of Audio Effects: LFX/GFX, SFX/MFX or SFX/EFX.
As far as I see in EqualizerAPO Configurator, SFX/EFX mode does not work with all audio devices for some reason.
For example, if I choose SFX/EFX for USB Headphones, it works good, but if I choose SFX/EFX for Realtek(R) Audio, it does not work at all, so I should choose SFX/MFX for Realtek(R) Audio.
Question 1: Is this possible to create APO with the same placement of audio effects for all devices?
I just want to create auto installation of my APO object, and does not care about audio effects placement for each device.
Question 2: Is this possible to setup APO for master channel? so audio processing will be applied to any device that will be selected as general audio device
